# SQL Query to add timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table in our ERP system that tracks the status of shop orders. It has the open date (column name ORGDUE_10) and Status column (STATUS_10) which has codes 1-6, and status 3 is an open order, status 4 is closed (the rest of the codes do not matter for this application). Unfortunately, this table does not have a timestamp column where I can get the date when the order is closed. I need to determine if multiple Shop Orders were closed (STATUS_10 changed from 3 to 4) on time or if they went past the due date (ORGDUE_10).

Any ideas how I could do a query that will accomplish this? I assume I need a another table – write the data to it and then some kind of trigger?

I am using VS2015. The Table Name that I cannot edit is Order_Master

```
STATUS_10     ORDNUM_10   PRTNUM_10      CURDUE_10
4         |   50015246    |ASY5670    |  9/4/2017 
3         |   50016983    |ASY5699    |  5/15/2017
```

Comment: Basically, you'll need a table that records the close date — either modify 'a Table' to add a suitable column, or create 'another Table' to hold the shop order number and the close date, with inserts to that being driven by a trigger on the main table detecting when the status goes to 4.  Note that tables have names — if you can't quote the one you've really got, fake one (SHOP_ORDERS, for example).  It is astonishing (to me, at any rate) how often people ask SQL questions and don't give the table names.

Comment: @Jonathon Leffler, thanks for your speedy response. the Table name that I cannot edit is Order_Master. I have created a second table Called SO_Status and columns Status (nchar10), CurDue (Date), and added Comp_Date (date). I sincerely apologize for missing these details in my original question.

Comment: You're not alone in missing such information — it is a common problem.  I'm not currently sure whether you need help with creating the trigger or with creating the SQL to select from the two tables now that you have the trigger in place.    Your sample data has `CURDUE_10`; your text mentions `ORGDUE_10` and not `CURDUE_10`.  I think you'll need to provide some sample data for the second table — it would be good to have a couple of rows that were overdue and a couple that were not, and the corresponding data from `Order_Master`.  It would be useful to have the expected output. (MCVE — [MCVE]).

Comment: I think I can get through selecting from the two tables. CURDUE_10 and ORGDUE_10 seem to interchange in their documentation - I specifically want to use CURDUE_10 (sorry for the mix up). I will need help with the trigger as I am completely clueless. So - for the sake of clarity; I would like to have a trigger on Order_Master (Status_10 changes from 3 to 4) that will UPDATE SO_Status (Comp_date) the date of this change. I sincerely appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out (I think). Here is the code I used which seems to do the trick. this code will update, insert, and conditionally timestamp (datestamp) two different tables on two different servers. I hope this makes sense and helps someone else. I appreciate the help given @Jonathan Leffler, sorry I didn't make it easy on you.

```
MERGE server2.dbo.table2 AS target /* the added server.dbo is in the event the two tables are 
on different sql servers*/
USING server1.dbo.table1 AS source ON (target.column-t = source.column-s) /* 
column-t is the target column and column-s is the matching source column */
WHEN MATCHED AND (conditional column) AND (antoher conditional column) THEN
UPDATE SET
    column-t = source.column-s, column-t (for datestamp) = (GETDATE())
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND (conditional column) AND (antoher conditional 
column)THEN     /* you cannot use a WHERE clause in a MERGE but you can set 
up similar conditions in the WHEN statements */
INSERT (target columns)
VALUES (source columns in same order as target columns);
```